# Image not taking full height/width when displayed

Tags: html, image, css

I have two of the same image. I display one of those images almost all the time, the only exception is in the viewport of 1001px - 1400px I display a cropped version of the image. For some reason the cropped image `laptop2` in the `div` id of `company-information-block2-2` doesn't scale the full width of 100% and `height: auto`. I cannot figure out why because the image above it is structered the exact same way.

I created a fiddle to show it. Please go in and out of the viewport 1001-1400.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n8udyrn4/)

```
.section-blocks {
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.section-block-img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.laptop2 {
    display: none;
}
#company-information-block2, #company-information-block2-2 {
    height: auto;
}


/*----------------------------------------------MEDIA QUERY 1001 - 1400--------------------------*/

@media screen and (min-width: 1001px) and (max-width:1400px) {

.laptop2 {
    display: block;
}
.laptop {
    display: none;
}

}
    <div id="company-information"><div id="company-information-block1" class="section-blocks">
            <div class="company-container">
                <div class="company-information-block-title mobile-none">ABC ABC</div>
                <div class="company-information-block-title2 mobile-none">THE COMPANY</div>
                <div class="company-information-block-description">Knowledge and experience are some of the words to describe
                The Company. This company is a third generation, family-owned business that has been providing 
                regional services for over 60 years. The creative direction included a clean, modern and
                simplistic approach for visitors to learn more about them. Functionally we knew showcasing services and projects
                was the main objective. Viewing the multiple project photos and services is easy because of the dashboard approach. 
                The job summaries do not blend in together to allow each specific category to instantly catch the eye of their target 
                market.
                </div>
        </div>
        </div><div id="company-information-block2" class="section-blocks"><img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/work/projects/eslich/laptop.jpg" alt="Optimun Designs Responsive Design" class="section-block-img laptop">
        <div id="company-information-block2-2" class="section-blocks"><img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/work/projects/eslich/laptop2.jpg" alt="Optimun Designs Responsive Design" class="section-block-img laptop2">
        </div></div>
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/n8udyrn4/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like its because your .section-blocks class has a width: 50% rule which is wrapped around that image. If you add a class to that div wrapping the image in question that makes its width 100%, the image should do what you want it to.

Here is a forked version of your fiddle with it working https://jsfiddle.net/mz50xje7/

I just added this class to that div:

```
.test{
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I believe I am getting margin on either vertical side of the image displayed due to the other image displayed none. Is there anyway to get rid of that whitespace?

Comment: @Becky I am not sure what margin you mean other than the default 8px margin that comes from the body tag. You can remove that by doing: body{ margin: 0px }

Comment: It isn't from the body. I am referring to the live page now. It was happening before I posted the question and still now. Does the image tags give off margin naturally?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9zumx3x0/ i removed the body margin here, the img tags in this fiddle have no margins, and neither do the ones in your original fiddle

Answer (score 1):

This is because the second image, `.laptop2` is nested inside two `.section-blocks` divs in total, whereas the first image `.laptop` is only nested in one. This becomes clearer when you just look at a simplified version of the HTML structure:

```
<div class="section-blocks">
  <img class="section-block-img laptop">
  <div class="section-blocks">
    <img class="section-block-img laptop2">
  </div>
</div>
```

As the `.section-blocks` has a width of 50%, the inner `.section-blocks` takes up 50% of the width of it's parent element. This reduces the width of the inner `.section-blocks` to 25% of the page width and makes your second image take up exactly half the width of the first image.